# Sony Vaio Laptop not booting - black screen

Tags: windows-7, linux, ubuntu, sony-vaio

I have a Sony Vaio laptop - not sure on exact model as I am not at home currently - can post later if required.  I have it dual boot running Linux (Ubuntu 12.04 LTS (Precise Pangolin)) and also Windows 7.  I upgraded the Linux version to the LTS about a month ago.  Before that I never had any issues like what is happening now althouh I dont think the OS upgrade is related to my current problem but it suppose it could be.

Basically when I power on my computer - it shows a black screen, sounds as if it is trying to boot, then the fan kicks in briefly for approx 3-5 seconds but then it stops and the green power light around the power button over on the left of the keyboard goes off.  I have tried with the Battery out and connected to just mains and get same result.  I have tried with just battery and AC not plugged in and same result.  I have double checked the CD Drive to make sure its is empty - there is no usb or anything else connected.  Anyone have any ideas of things I could try to work out what is going wrong.  If any more info is needed let me know and I will try and edit the question to provide this.

Many Thanks

Comment: Can you boot from disc? Stick in the W7 disc and see if that gets you further? Or, press F8 on boot to see if allows you deeper in (or not). If either of these work, it may rule out a BIOS issue (or not)

Comment: Also, make sure the RAM didn't become loose.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Dave - will try pressing F8 on boot this evening.  I dont have a W7 disk - I dont think anyway - think it came all installed.

Comment: Does your boot screen shows any message now or have shown message "CPU fan speed low", if this is the case you need to change CPU fan. This could also be the reason for your computer not starting up. Alternatively dust may also create such problem hope this is not the case!

Comment: @DarshanJoshi - it hasnt shown me any message at all - black screen is all - the fan does however run at full speed all the time on Ubuntu - meant to look into the change needed to fix that so perhaps that could have burned it out???  I do have can off compressed air for removing dust from PC - might open it up and give a good clean out and see if that helps at all.